# String not displaying correctly

Tags: bug, status-declined, syntax-highlighting

I just answered my own question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11401500/how-do-i-load-a-svg-file-thats-been-generated-with-php/11414930#11414930) (GeoPheonix answered in the comments but didn't provide a full answer), and the string in the code isn't displaying correctly:

[image: string error]

This may seem like a minor nitpick but in this case it could cause confusion as the issue was related to the `?>`.  (and as we all know, [users shouldn't have to think](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2005/08/dont-make-me-think-second-edition.html))

Comment: Sorry I tried to edit but didn't do a very good job. What if you use double-quotes in both cases, e.g. `echo "stuff\"otherstuff"` - maybe this won't trip up the syntax highlighter so badly? Anyway there are some cases that just aren't always handled perfectly by the syntax highlighter, e.g. strings that end in \ like `SET @folder = 'd:\folder\';` - this wreaks havoc on the syntax highlighting until the next `'` is hit. You could spend a lot of time trying to work around this or you can just trust that readers will copy the code and only bitch and moan if it actually doesn't work.

Comment: Cheated and told the highlighter it was Javascript ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem the syntax highlighter is having here is actually very similar to the problem the user in that question had: Prettify sees the *first* `?>` and considers it to end the PHP part of the code, not realizing that it appears in a string constant.

Given the way prettify works, this unfortunately is unfixable. It's similar to why you shouldn't have `</script>` in a JavaScript string constant within an HTML page – at the time that the ending tag is seen, the parser doesn't yet know about the concept of string constants.

Fortunately this is just a small edge case, and Daniel Fischer has [found](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/139252/string-not-displaying-correctly#comment392356_139252) a nice workaround.